# Parse.com - custom notifications vs setDefaultPushCallback - starting wrong activity

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform

### Goal

- Mobile app with Parse's back-end
- User creates message to all/admins/specific users
- The "recipients" get notification that they have new message
- When the notification is clicked, details about the message are displayed

### Current approach

I create a custom push in the afterSave cloud code method. The call looks like this:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where : query,
    data : {
        action : "com.acme.CUSTOM_ACTION_GOES_HERE",
        content : messageContent
    }
}).then(...
```

(The query is defined to get specific `Parse.Installation` objects.)

In Android app, I have a BroadcastReceiver registered like this

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.acme.CUSTOM_ACTION_GOES_HERE" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the onReceive method of the broadcastreceiver, I create custom notification where I also define the pending intent starting an activity when the notification is clicked:

```
Intent contentIntent = new Intent(context, DisplayDetailsActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(DisplayDetailsActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(contentIntent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
.setContentTitle("New message")
.setContentText(content)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_message)
.setNumber(notificationsCount)
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.build();
noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mgr.notify(555, noti);
```

### Problem

Without calling (e.g. in application's `onCreate` method)

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), SomeActivity.class);
```

... the pushes are not delivered to the device

When using that call, the activity `SomeActivity` is started when the notification is clicked instead of the activity `DisplayDetailsActivity` set in the intent in the broadcast receiver.

When I have just one type of custom notification, it is possible to call the `setDefaultPushCallback` with the `DisplayDetailsActivity.class` as second parameter.

However, I plan to have multiple different custom notifications, and clicking each of them should start different activity. In such case the workaround mentioned above is not viable option any more.

## Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

After working on this for a few hours I stumbled upon this post, I started from @pareshgoel workaround, the basic idea is to remove the need to register an Activity or subscribe to a Channel if it is not required and also lower the server requests for the `Installation` class.

I took the Parse-1.5.1.jar, from Parse.com and using JD-GUI I looked in `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(Context context, Class<? extends Activity> cls)`.

What it does is

`if cls is null remove subscription; 
 create subscription for new cls;
 call  PushService.startServiceIfRequired`

The function `PushService.startServiceIfRequired` starts parse push service if GCM is not supported on the device or sends a registration request to GCM, waits for the registration_id, and upon arrival updates the installation device token.

My workaround is to use : [PushService.startServiceIfRequired](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/PushService.html#startServiceIfRequired(android.content.Context)) - which doesn't seem to be documented, you can use if after the initialize or if you have users after login/signup, as it is using a background task it can be called on the main thread.

Another advantage is that using `PushService.startServiceIfRequired` you have 2 server requests to save/update the `Installation` class, first one sets push type to GCM and the second sets pushtype to GCM, sets device token to registration_id. `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback` introduces an initial server request.

Comment: One of my devices just would not receive push notifications. This brought it to life again, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and have a workaround.

First of all setDefaultPushCallback needs to be called to have Parse push notification working. This is most likely a bug n Parse. I am on Parse Android 1.5.1 .

The workaround is to not set the "alert" param in the parse push notification send code.
If this is not set, then Parse will not display the alert on its own, and your custom broadcast receiver could handle the push.

Push notification in Parse need some more bug fixing before it could be reliably used.